# Solve error file compiling PHP configure: error: libXpm.(a|so) not found

Tags: software-installation, php, compiling, install-from-source

I got an error while compiling PHP, I am listing the details below.

```
Error configure error libxpm.(a so) not found
```

I have checked with dpkg -L libxpm-dev. it is showing the needed file is in the folder 
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`(libXpm.a).

I have tried with `--with-xpm-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but error still exists.

Answer (score 3):

I got past this by doing

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.a /usr/lib/libXpm.a
```

You can also set the lib dir by adding

```
'--with-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
```

to the configure line but that missed some of the ones in /usr/lib.

Comment: Hello Jacek, Thank you, I have tried with both options, none of them works for me :(. Also I got another error("checking for db4 major version... configure: error: Header contains different version") while I am trying to include "--with-db4"

Answer (score 1):

Hello I solved couple of problems via this link I hope it would help you.

http://zgadzaj.com/how-to-install-php-53-and-52-together-on-ubuntu-1204

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.